# Searching for a character in a named list in R

Tags: r, list, string-comparison

I have a named list and want to search if a character string appears in it.

```
data_list <- list()
data_list$item1 <- c("hello_world"="hi", "snooker cue"="cue")
data_list$item2 <- c("property"="house")
```

When I see if "cue" is in the list by doing `"cue"%in%data_list` the result is `FALSE` but it is in there under `data_list$item1`. How can I search to see if strings appear in the list and return TRUE if they do?

Answer (score 3):

`unlist` your data to access the list elements:

```r
"cue" %in% unlist(data_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note here that `%in%` returns one value for each of the left operand (here, just "cue"), can be interpreted "is the left value(s) contained in the right vector". On the contrary, `==` will return one value for each of the left operand and can only accept a vector of length 1 on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

If the location (`item`) should be returned as well:

```
> lapply(data_list, \(v) "cue" %in% v)
$item1
[1] TRUE

$item2
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `grepl`?

```
> grepl('cue', unlist(data_list)) |> any()
[1] TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(data_list)
list(item1 = c(hello_world = "hi", `snooker cue` = "cue"), item2 = c(property = "house"))
```